# How Do I Get To Preferences In FireFox

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

I'm currently trying to get to preferences in FireFox in Linux Ubuntu.  Because I don't have 10 reputation, I can't post an image (otherwise I would).  All I see in the browser is the `Address Bar`, `Downloads` and `Home`.  If I right-click (or left click) on any of these, I don't have further options (other than Home, but it only allows me to add items to the toolbar, none of which are `Preferences/Options/Etc`).

- I tried vising a website to see if more options would open; nothing.
- I tried right clicking on the main page and each toolbar item (listed) to see if there was another options like "Preferences" or "Options"; nothing.
- I tried entering "Preferences" in the address bar, thinking maybe it would open automatically; nothing.
- I tried right clicking on FireFox on the Linux Menu to see if I could open options without opening the program (and tried this even when the program was open); nothing.

Comment: Solved: in the address bar, type `about:preferences`.

Comment: Same problem happens on Mac. Preferences and about menu items are missing or moved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried One experiment, i.e. to move my mouse to the top of the screen when firefox was in tiled mode & then again in maximized mode. Both occasions the menu appears. If the menu does not show, it could be in maximized mode. Hit F11 to toggle between full screen & "normal" mode.

Once you have that housekeeping out of the way, you're ready to shoot into preferences.

From the menu above, click on edit. The last item is preferences.

Comment: Added to your answer so that I can mark it as the answer; thanks!

Comment: @user123: Feel free to add an answer yourself and mark it as accepted. Answering your own questions is encouraged.